# jQuery - load content into a div onclick, show() and hide()

Tags: jquery

I have a simple menu with `<ul`>s, every ul loads its content into a div onclicking it.
 
Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/41. 
On first you open the page you can see the default content (First div) fading in, I want it to do not fade in, just to be loaded as it is without animation(JUST for the first div(the default one)).
Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('current')) return;
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your CSS :

```
.pbox {display:none}
#div1 {display:block}
```

and remove the trigger

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/54/)

Comment: It's set once you click something, if it's needed on pageload, it can just be added to the first element.

Comment: The same question about the current element was asked of me and according to the OP's fiddle, it's set on the first list element anyway so nothing extra is required.

Comment: @j08691 - Yeah, I noticed it was set in the markup in the fiddle as well, so the question doesn't make sense, neither does the OP's selection of answer based on setting something that is already set, but I guess there really is one born every minute. Moving along!

Comment: @adeneo - agreed. Plus the accepted answer doesn't even work.

Comment: The best solution, just have to set the class to .current

Comment: Guys I'm testing in Opera here. Nothing works at all with jQuery 2.0.2, and that includes both your fiddles. Under 1.9.1 and after removing `class="current"` from the HTML, my solution works just fine so don't get so excited. Moving along!

Answer (score 2):

Change your jQuery to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EPvGf/52/)**

I removed the `.find('a:first').click()` at the end that triggers the issue you're having, and added a `$('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();` to hide all but the first div.

Comment: One problem, the default value in the menu doesn't show that it's loaded

Comment: Try the person under your solution's solution, it keeps every thing as it is, you aren't :(

Comment: Anyway I voted up, it was great code although it isn't complete

Comment: The first list item has the current class set by default.

Comment: What do you mean by "Try the person under your solution's solution, it keeps every thing as it is, you aren't"? Are you referring to adeneo's solution or Beetroot-Beetroot's?

Comment: Nevermind, I had to add class="current" to get it work, it works perfect but the first solution is the best, anyway THANK YOU very much

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable to determine the fadeIn/fadeOut time as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fadeTime = 0;
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('current')) return;
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(fadeTime);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(fadeTime);
        fadeTime = 600;
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

On first call, `fadeTime` will be zero, thereafter 600.

This has the advantage, as in the original code in the question, of not needing a separate mechanism for setting "current" on the first selected element.

### Edit

To make this work, you should also remove `class="current"` from the HTML.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ST4sJ/)

Comment: I now released that your solution is the best because it keeps everything as it have to be, the other not.

Comment: @user2401856 - this solution fails for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EPvGf/55/

Comment: Yeah, where possible it's a good idea to initialize things with the same code that handles user interactions.

Comment: j08691, try jQuery 1.9.1 instead of 2.0.2. I'm afraid I don't know 2.0.2 well enough yet to know why there should be a difference.

Comment: Why would that matter, the first anchor already has the class `current` by default, so the function returns when you trigger the click, and it does nothing ?

Comment: Adeano, good point! See edit.